# HTTP 404 after following all the required path and instruction

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I like to create a connection between MySQL, and Tomcat. I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hsrl4kxK2Ro) tutorial and did as suggested. I created a index.jsp file C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.73\webapps\test location. Then copy paste the jar file in lib folder. I start the tomcat server from command prompt.

The url for running the index.jsp page is `http://localhost:8080/webapps/test/index.jsp`

But I got HTTP status 404 error.

I can find the test folder from `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` here. But if I click on it to open I got HTTP status error.

The JSP code is:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Random" %>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
</head>

<%
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospitalm", "root", "1234");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    int i = 0;
    String qry = "select * from patient";

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

    while (rs.next()) {
        String item = rs.getString(1);
        out.println(item + "<br>");
    }

    con.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
%>
```

I cannot understand what is the difference between my work and the video lecture.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp` as the url

Comment: In modern Java architecture we don't use JSP's anymore. Check out for example the Spring Boot framework how to build modern Java applications. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: @f1sh Yeah I have tried this one as well but did not work.

Comment: @JasperHuzen That's my project requirement.  I cannot change JSP with Spring Boot.

Comment: @f1sh Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130366/taking-input-variables-from-a-tablehtml-and-supply-the-values-as-a-variable-na